# How to Open Visual Studio 2013 Solution in MonoDevelop

Tags: linux-mint, mono

My Toshiba Laptop had started running slow recently and, quite frankly, I was tired of Windows 8, so I created a USB of the most recent version of Linux Mint and installed it, moving all my needed projects to GitHub.

I installed MonoDevelop because I know of its tendency for WinForms, but when I try opening the .sln file it opens it in a text editor in MonoDevelop rather than as a solution. I have two major Solutions I need to develop [Yahtzee](http://github.com/apotter96/Yahtzee) and [GemsCraft](http://github.com/apotter96/GemsCraft/).

How do I open these solutions in MonoDevelop? Yahtzee is in VisualBasic and GemsCraft is in C#

Comment: Perhaps this question could be migrated to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MonoDevelop 4.2.2 supports Visual Studio 2013 Solutions normally, but you will need change ToolsVersion in your projects. Open each one of the projects in your solution, but open using a text editor your .csproj file and change `ToolsVersion="12.0"` to `ToolsVersion="4.0"`,

Comment: what is the impact of such update ? won't that confuse VS ?

Comment: VS deals with this pretty good (at least 2012 and 2015), so, dont worry